# click button to reactivate autohidden-div not working, fiddle Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a panel to show up for five seconds after a button is clicked....

Then if the user click on the panel (uses it...) the panel continues showing up,otherwise it hides for inactivation.

So the panel can increase its lifespan if the user uses it (click or hover on it)...otherwise it just fadeOut

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to use `clearTimeout` but it ends up in a wierd behaviour snippet. I tried reseting with booleans the code but as well...I couldnt make it work the way is expected

```js
 
  let ShowPanel = 0;
 $('.ShowPanel5Seconds').on("click", function() {
      ShowPanel = 1;

      $(".Panel").show();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".Panel").fadeOut();
      }, 5000)


    });

    //clicking hoverin on the panel

     $('.Panel,.container').on("click", function(event) {
      if (1 == ShowPanel) {

        $('.ShowPanel5Seconds').trigger("click");
       }
     });
```

```css
     .container{
       position:relative; 
       width:300px;
       height:300px;
       border:1px solid blue;
       margin:10px
        }
      .Panel {
      display: none;
      position:absolute;
      top:10px;
      left:10px;
      background: red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <button class="ShowPanel5Seconds">Show Panel 5 seconds</button>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="Panel">I'm the panel...click me to continue living</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it. Just show/extend time in one go

```js
let panel = $('.Panel'),
    panelTimer;

function showAndExtendPanel(){
  panel.stop(true,true).show();
  clearTimeout(panelTimer);
  panelTimer = setTimeout(killPanel, 5000)
}

function killPanel(){
  panel.fadeOut();
}

$('.ShowPanel5Seconds, .Panel').on("click", showAndExtendPanel);
```

```css
.Panel {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="ShowPanel5Seconds">Show Panel 5 seconds</button>

<div class="Panel">I'm the panel...click me to continue living</div>
```

Comment: I updated the question for a better understanding...but this is what I needed...!!!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, that works as expected is to keep a timeout variable with the time left to display the div.

```js
let timeleft = 0;

function hide_or_not() {
  timeleft = timeleft - 1;
  if (timeleft <= 0) {
    $(".Panel").fadeOut();
  }
  setTimeout(hide_or_not, 1000);
}

$('.ShowPanel5Seconds').on("click", function() {
  $(".Panel").show();
  if (timeleft <= 0) {
    timeleft = 5;
    hide_or_not();
  }
});

//clicking hoverin on the panel

$('.Panel').on("click", function(event) {
  timeleft = timeleft + 1;
});
```

```css
.Panel {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
<scri
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="ShowPanel5Seconds">Show Panel 5 seconds</button>

<div class="Panel">I'm the panel...click me to continue living</div>
```

*Note: The code is made to be readable, not exactly optimal.*

Answer (score 1):

You can control this by `addClass`, `removeClass()` and `:not()` selector

```js
// on button click show/fadeOut the panel but not the panel with class hover
$('.ShowPanel5Seconds').on("click", function() {
  $(".Panel:not(.hover)").show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".Panel:not(.hover)").fadeOut();
  }, 5000)
});

// when hover over the panel add class hover and remove it when unhover and trigger the button click
$('.Panel:not(.hover)').hover(function(event){
  $(this).addClass('hover');
} , function(){
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
  $('.ShowPanel5Seconds').click();
});
```

```css
.Panel {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="ShowPanel5Seconds">Show Panel 5 seconds</button>

<div class="Panel">I'm the panel...click me to continue living</div>
```

Comment: ok. this is a good approach, but if you click on the red panel several times...it just doesnt dissapear for a long long time...

Comment: @joe No it doesn't .. the `hover` class will automatically removed after the hover out.. be sure to hover out the panel after more and more click .. may be your css style keep the hover on